# Transfer perl output line by line to a file via unix command

Tags: perl, unix

I created a small perl programm in a unix enviroment:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict; 
use warnings; 

my $counter = 0;  
while ($counter < 10) {
  printf "%s\n", $counter;
  $counter++;  
  sleep(2);
}
```

If I start this at command line it will count from 0 to 9 in 20 seconds. That's what I want.

But if I use a command to transfer output to a file (`myprog.pl >> myprog.log`) then the output will be written at once at the end of the program (after 20 sec).

I want that the program writes it output line by line to the file. So after 10 seconds there should be 5 lines in `myprog.log`. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: No need for printf().  `print "$counter\n";` will do what you want.

Comment: One-liner with autoflush: `perl -we '$|=1; $\="\n"; sleep 2 and print $i while $i++ < 10;'`

Comment: @TLP, close but not an exact mimic.  You print 1..10 pausing before each number, the OP prints 0..9 pausing after each.  FWIW, `-l` could more compactly take the place of `$\="\n"`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's expected buffering behavior, but your script can [change that](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24|).

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict; 
use warnings; 

$| = 1; # <------- Enable autoflush    

my $counter = 0;  
while ($counter < 10) {
  printf "%s\n", $counter;
  $counter++;  
  sleep(2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An interesting discussion on the subject: http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html